# Bash : Adding thread-capability to this bash function, so it's faster

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell, optimization

I have a bash-function which I regularly use to list files and directories in a nice format. The problem is, that everytime I execute the function, it takes about 2-3 seconds till the data listing is finally finished.

As I am calling the find command two times, it takes double time. I wanted to ask, how can I start both the find commands as thread in parallel and then get the output. I presume this will make the function output load faster. Am I wrong?

Script :

```
function lsa
{
 # Function to stat files and folders in current dir
 # Takes first argument as directory to stat
 # If no directory supplied, current dir assumed
 if [ -z "$1" ];then
   DIR="."
 else
   DIR="$1"
 fi

 # print directories first
 printf "*** DIRECTORIES *** \n"
 find "$DIR"  -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "."   -printf "%M %u %g "  -exec du -sh  {} \; 2> /dev/null 
 # print non-directories second
 printf "*** FILES *** \n"

 find "$DIR"  -maxdepth 1 ! -type d ! -name "."   -printf "%M %u %g "  -exec du -sh  {} \; 2> /dev/null 
 }
```

Kindly let me know. Thank you.

*Update*

**With changes** :

```
*** DIRECTORIES *** 
[1] 6882
*** FILES *** 
[2] 6883
[1]-  Done                    find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "." -printf "%M %u %g " -exec du -sh {} \; 2> /dev/null > dirs
[2]+  Done                    find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 ! -type d ! -name "." -printf "%M %u %g " -exec du -sh {} \; 2> /dev/null > non-dirs
// And then the files and dirs one after other
```

**Without changes** :

```
borg@borg-cube:~$lsa
*** DIRECTORIES *** 
// All directories
*** FILES *** 
// All files
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multi-**threads** but multi-**processes** by running the two find commands in background and saving their outputs to different files. Then `wait` both find commands completion and concatenate the outputs (dirs first).

This way...

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "."   -printf "%M %u %g "  -exec du -sh  {} \; 2> /dev/null > dirs &
...
find "$DIR"  -maxdepth 1 ! -type d ! -name "."   -printf "%M %u %g "  -exec du -sh  {} \; 2> /dev/null > non-dirs &
...
wait
cat dirs non-dirs
....
```

** UPDATE **

Replace `cat dirs non-dirs` at the end with:

```
printf "*** DIRECTORIES *** \n"
cat dirs
printf "*** FILES *** \n"
cat non-dirs
```

Comment: The performance is quite better with your changes, just the formatting is getting messed up because a background process is created with &. I am updating the main post, a moment please.

Comment: The fix is trivial.  Don't print the headings until you have the results.  Or move this to an external script; then the process IDs will not be printed to your terminal.